# How to enter multiple array formula

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

Is there any way to do "Ctrl+Shift+Enter" on multiple cells containing formula? I want to turn them all into array.

I googled for the solution, and it tells me to select them all, hit F2 to go into edit mode, then Ctrl+Shift+Enter, but that converts all other array formulas into the first one!

Example: I have cells going down vertically with the following formula in them:

```
=INDEX(Data!V2:V64, SMALL(IF(W2=Data!B2:B64, ROW(Data!B2:B64)-MIN(ROW(Data!B2:B64))+1, ""), ROW(A1)))
=INDEX(Data!V2:V64, SMALL(IF(W2=Data!B2:B64, ROW(Data!B2:B64)-MIN(ROW(Data!B2:B64))+1, ""), ROW(A2)))
=INDEX(Data!V2:V64, SMALL(IF(W2=Data!B2:B64, ROW(Data!B2:B64)-MIN(ROW(Data!B2:B64))+1, ""), ROW(A3)))
=INDEX(Data!V2:V64, SMALL(IF(W2=Data!B2:B64, ROW(Data!B2:B64)-MIN(ROW(Data!B2:B64))+1, ""), ROW(A4)))
=INDEX(Data!V2:V64, SMALL(IF(W2=Data!B2:B64, ROW(Data!B2:B64)-MIN(ROW(Data!B2:B64))+1, ""), ROW(A5)))
=INDEX(Data!V2:V64, SMALL(IF(W2=Data!B2:B64, ROW(Data!B2:B64)-MIN(ROW(Data!B2:B64))+1, ""), ROW(A6)))
...
```

What is the fastest way without editing each cell individually then hitting Ctrl+Shift+Enter?

Appreciate any help

Comment: Go to the first formula - lock all your multi-cell ranges with F4(so that $ appears before the columns AND row numbers), use Ctrl-Shift-Enter, then copy down...

Comment: Perfect MacroMarc, appreciate the tip

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

1. `=INDEX(Data!V2:V64, SMALL(IF(W2=Data!B2:B64, ROW(Data!B2:B64)-MIN(ROW(Data!B2:B64))+1, ""), ROW(A:A)))`
2. If first formula is in the first row, you can use this:

   `=INDEX(Data!V2:V64, SMALL(IF(W2=Data!B2:B64, ROW(Data!B2:B64)-MIN(ROW(Data!B2:B64))+1, ""), ROW()))`

So you Row as reference to current row.